# Matlab: Matrix of ClassificationKNN class objects

Tags: class, matlab, object, vector, matrix

For classification I'm building a number of models for a classifier in MATLAB. I use the class `ClassificationKNN` for this.
I would very much like to store multiple models (or objects of this class) inside a matrix.
Normally you could access and create matrices inside a matrix with the curly braces ({}).
My loop looks like this:

```
models = []
for i = 1:length(x)
    models = [models, {ClassificationKNN.fit(x,y)}]
end
```

Unfortunately this returns a matrix models of size (1,3) but all cells are empty which means the models are lost...
How can I make sure every model is stored in a matrix? I need to do this because I need all models later in my calculations and the position in the matrix is important...
Any ideas?

Comment: It's been a while since i've MATLABed so I could be wrong, but the [a,{b}] syntax bothers me. I can google it a bit later but i'd stare at that first. Also, if you know length(x), always preallocate your matrices, growing one in a loop is sooo much slower

Comment: Yep, preallocation the matrices is a good idea. I will look into that some more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a cell array of models, right?  It sure looks that way, if that will work try this:

```
models = {}
for ii = 1:length(x)
    models = [models, {ClassificationKNN.fit(x,y)}]
end
```

Also, you loop through calling `ClassificationKNN.fit(x,y)` with the same arguments every time, is this just a test, or pseudo-code for an example.  Like the comment says, it's best to preallocate like:

```
models = cell(length(x),1);
for ii = 1:length(x)
    models{ii} = ClassificationKNN.fit(x,y);
end
```

But, either way is likely fine.

Comment: I used dummy code to clarify my question a bit more, in the real code I use different parameters each time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to macduffs post I finally figured out what was going on. Whilest reading his proposition I realised that that indeed should be the correct way if getting a cell array of objects. 
After trying it, the array again seemed empty when opening it in the variable editor. I tried calling the first cell in the array to see if it was indeed empty and it was not. It returned the object I had stored in it. This means the question was answered. 
I then reverted back to my own method to see if that worked as well and it did. When calling a cell it also returned an object.

Bottom line:
Do not trust the variable editor ^^.